# Java Timer schedule task: servive JVM shutdown?

Tags: java, timer

Java Timer schedule task: servive JVM shutdown?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)
```

After JVM is shutdown, will the task scheduled still be executed?

Comment: .............no

Comment: No. It will not.

Answer (score 0):

It won't survive the shutdown. The underlying thread will terminate.

Moreover, the termination will occur in an abrupt way since the JVM doesn't try to [stop the application threads](http://www.javabyexamples.com/guide-to-jvm-shutdown#application-threads-thread-pools) during a shutdown.